# How to make sublist uses the same enumeration style

Tags: lists, enumerate

1. I need to make the sublist uses the same enumeration style.

What I get is:

```
1) 
    a)
    b)
2)
```

I need:

```
1) 
    1.1)
    1.2)
2)
```

2. In another case, how can I change the enumeration of the main list from numbers to letters?

This is the script:

```
\documentclass[journal,comsoc]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}
\title{Test}
\maketitle
\section{Listing}
\subsection{Sub Section} 
\begin{enumerate}
    \item First
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item First First
            \item First Second
        \end{enumerate}
    \item Second
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would you mind posting a *compilable* code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to @Bernard answer (+1), but use of `enumi` counter:

```
\documentclass[journal,comsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\section{Listing}
\subsection{Sub Section}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item First
        \begin{enumerate}[label=\theenumi.\arabic*),leftmargin=*]
            \item First First
            \item First Second
        \end{enumerate}
    \item Second
        \begin{enumerate}[label=\theenumi.\arabic*),leftmargin=*]
            \item First First
            \item First Second
        \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solves the incompatibility problem with `label*`! (+1).

Answer (score 1):

Very simple with `enumitem`: using the `label*` key prepends the parent counter to the sublist counter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\section{Listing}
\subsection{Sub Section}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item First
        \begin{enumerate}[label*=\arabic*)]
            \item First First
            \item First Second
        \end{enumerate}
    \item Second
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you try it with my template IEEEtran, it does not work.

Comment: That's why you always have to post a complete code. It seems  enumitem has soime incompatibilities with IEEEtran.